# Dependency Injection in Controller instead of module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a main module mainApp with many controllers and a filter and a factory. 
The problem which i am facing is that, if i a put a dependency in module like angularFileUpload in my module

> angular.module('mainApp', ['angularFileUpload'])

As every controller is linked to a webpage, i have to add angular file upload JS files in every webpage and the need of adding angular file upload JS files is only in one webpage.
If i don't add the js file in all webpages and when i access that webpage my app gets crashed.

Please someone tell me a solution.

Comment: Does your pages have seperate modules? Means , if you are really using different angular modules, then you can inject it accordingly.

Comment: No only one module. I got it what you are saying. Isn't there's any other way ?

Comment: if all your modules are for different pages, then i suppose you can create different js files so that you can inject your dependencies with ease in module for a particular page. Anyways, angularjs is a SPA framework, if you just have multiple pages, dont you feel Angularjs will be heavy?

Comment: okies...
I think website is performing better than jquery. And also i like Angular's, Declarative programming style. My pages and codes are smaller than before now.

Comment: If a page require lot of live updating , you can have that on Angualarjs. Also, there are various frameworks present that are lightweight and need writing like angular. You can use those to create other pages which dont need that much modifications, check riot.js, Maybe that will work for static pages. Also , there is always option of caching files, so asking for the js file with needed modeule in every page  will not be an issue

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs we are using for single page applications. So we are having only one web page. Please inject angularFileUpload module in app.module section & use their services, factories, directives in mainApp controllers, templates by injecting individual services, factories, directives what we are using.

All webpages means I didn't understood. And you should use ng-view or ui-view for going to other state/page.

Comment: We can't inject angularFileUpload module in controllers/services

Comment: I am not developing single page application. Angular is not only used for SPA. My every controller is used for a separate individual page